# How to rig hand after applying automatic weights?

Tags: rigging

I forgot to roll the bones while attaching that armature to the body. I have applied the automatic weights and all. So now how do I fix this.[image]

Comment: you can go into edit mode and fix the bone rolls.

Comment: Yes, i did that but it isnt working

Comment: could you please share the hand and the hand armature?

Comment: yes, I made the changes in edit mode (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G2n1lrCPV_PLJkg2Dad3XMZdbdKwSZJg/view?usp=share_link)  and still in pose mode it hadn't change (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BfXwmDnMs_aQFzBlPMd2UlmLXPuqpuS2/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: hello, it would help if you shared the armature + mesh

Comment: ok, here is the file (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fi-LK2FQ31bOEJrZt5c-Tch3n5rrHU1e/view?usp=share_link). Also, I have edited only my index finger till now, the rest of the fingers are with automatic weights.

Comment: I don't know the cause. It's strange. Look for small bones, MCH-f_index.0?_drv.L, in the rig object and try setting their rolls to -175 degrees.